# Cannot connect to google compute engine VM

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a problem with my Google Compute Engine VMs.

After creating the VM, the SSH connection and the FileZilla connection are good at the beginning.

However, over time, the screen to connect to SSH loops, and FileZilla throws this error and the connection fails:

```
Status: Server refused our key
Error: FATAL ERROR: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
```

> (I connect to the server using SFTP, and generate a key file using puttygen.)

These are what I have tried.

- Delete and re-create the instance
- Create another project and create new instance there
- Replace the key file with a new one

I didn't wrote wrong server address or adding wrong keyfile ; everything should work properly.

and in the firewall settings, all port forwarding is configured normally.

Why is this happening?

(The VM is with debian-10-buster-v20200618 / using it for game server

I have contacted Google with chat support once, but it's not supporting anymore.
because I'm using a free trial.

Although I used `enable-oslogin` value at the VM and SSH succeeds to connect, FileZilla is still not working.)

What I did and tested :

Firstly I created an instance fir the game server purpose. And when I create an istance and connected to SSH, I use sudo su and created a directory at /home. just make it easier to look at.

I install screen, java, locale and other stuffs.

but Suddenly filezilla and ssh connection stops working after a few minutes without notifying me.

I didn't do anything without these stuffs.

I reinstalled filezilla, also created a new key from puttygen and set the keyfile both filezilla and vm ; not working.

I even created a new project and created the instance ; same thing happens.

I clean up the metadata and SSH key. It's Not working.

I even contacted with google and doing conversation via email.
But since I don't have much time left the credits spend alone. So I wrote a article right here.

==============================================================================

[image: The Firewall Settings. Yes I have done with it And I'm tried adding 22 port and going to add 21 port (Google asked me to try 21 port.)]

And I'm like I said I'm using SFTP Protocol to connect my VM to transfer game server files.

If you're asking about SSH connection, I'm using default SSH button at the VM Instance list nothing special that I can tell more about...

Comment: Can you please provide a complete list of steps and/or commands your're using (both locally and on your VM) to get connected via SSH and FileZilla after you create a fresh Debian10 VM ? **For the testing puposes please also disable `os-login`.**

Comment: edited the article. Yes all problem happens when oslogin metadata is disabled. (FileZilla still have the same problem with or without the metadata value at the vm.)

Comment: one more problem is that firewalls are not working. Opened the port 25565 and tried joined the game ; not working. Port forward tester says that the port 25565 is closed.

Comment: (saying this if you're wondering : port 22 opened as default.)

Comment: What protocol are you using to connect to the VM ? And can you verify that you'r firewall rule is still there ? If you create one with too broad access then they are usually automatically removed after a few minutes without any warning or information.

Comment: edited the article. and the pictured that I attached with desc has a grammer error with it. forgive me about it.

Comment: info adding : firewall is working. tested with clean server file, worked. It was my fault due to not installing jdk version as 8. / FileZilla still not working though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

It was my fault configuring date and time + locales.

Changed to Linux Debian 9 stretch and used dpkg-reconfigure to configure it. Works without problem.

(I used cp -p /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Seoul /etc/localtime to change timezone. (I live in Korea) and changed locale settings by editing /etc/default/locale.)

How I changed it

Original :

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG="C.UTF-8"
```

My Version :

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG="ko_KR.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="ko_kr:ko"
```

after these settings, I get problems what I explained before. (check the article above.)

But I downgraded to Debian 9 (strech) (for some reason with jdk)
and used `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` and `dpkg-reconfigure locales` to change these settings.

After that I have no problems with the timezone and locales.

(Thank you W_B trying to help me.)

Comment: Please update your answer with more details what you did exactly (preferably all the commands) - that way it will be more vaulable to community. Thank you !

Comment: Edited the answer article. Tell me if the article has problems. Also I want to show thanks try to help me. So I wrote shortly at the end.

Comment: well it seams like the problem occured while I was setting JDK manually...

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your case - created a new VM (debian 10) with `oslogin` enabled.
Then I logged in from the browser, created `.ssh` directory in my home dir (`mkdir .ssh`). Then created an `authorized_keys` file inside and pasted my public key from my personal computer (it's a Mac and doesn't have `gcloud` installed; `touch authorized_keys`) and pasted my public key in this file (`id_rsa.pub`) with `nano authorized_keys`. Then saved (`ctrl + o`) and exited (`ctrl + x`).

My ssh key (on my personal computer) was created simply by using "ssh-keygen` command without any parameters.

To check if the key is in place and working try to ssh from another instance (`ssh myuser@myvm.ip.something`) and yoo should get a shell prompt.

After that I was able to create a new connection in the FileZilla (SFTP protocol, and chose `login type' to` key file' and selected my private key (stored in `.ssh/id_rsa`) file.

My connection is active for more than 2 hours and I can disconnect and connect again & transfer files both ways.

Please follow my directions and this should work. From what you've described your FileZilla config is the case here.

Also - if for some reason you still can't connect [create a firewall rule](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/) to allow traffic on port 22.

Comment: please wait a moment while google has completely done with my situation ; if google fails to solve this I'll try your method. (too bad that I need to setup it at every vm. and I can't fully understand what you're talking about.. cause' I'm not good at GCE, this is my first time having some issues with it.)

Comment: posting this article on email with google's conversation ; for supporting purposes I hope.